# Django Many-To-Many Relationships between two models

Tags: python, django

I'm building a web app to help me manage my classes. So I have a Class model and a Student model and I want each Class to have multiple Students and I want each Student to be able to enroll in multiple Classes:

```
class Class(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
enrolled_students = models.ManyToManyField('Student', blank=True)

...

class Student(models.Model):
enrolled_classes = models.ManyToManyField(Class, blank=True)
```

This works just fine but it's tedious. I create a class and then I create a student and add the enrolled class. And then I have to go BACK into the class and enroll the student.  How do I automate this process so that Django automatically keeps track of which students are in which classes and which classes have which students enrolled?

I'm sure there's something simple that I'm missing or not understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do this at all. All relationship fields, including many-to-many, automatically add a backwards accessor. Just define the field on one side of the relation; for example, if you define it on Class, you can refer to the classes a student is enrolled in as `my_student.class_set.all()`.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/) lists out the ways to access related objects via the different relationship fields.